# Архитектура БД для мультиязычных сайтов

Tags: php, sql, архитектура, multilanguage

Да много тем тут уже подобного плана, но чет я свое не нашел. Поделитесь пожалуйста идеями как бы вы реализовали архитектуру БД для мультиязычного сайта.

Я бы выбрал вариант с полным дублированием сущности (поста, страницы, объявления и тд) и перевода всех полей на нужный язык ([скриншот](http://prntscr.com/ptuyyx)). Но тут некая трудность, как их адекватно связать, чтобы в будущем проблем со скоростью при выборке не было? Идейка была завести поле в таблице сущности related_entities и в неё класть массив в формате json с ключами языков и значениями id связанных сущностей, но что-то сомневаюсь в этом решении.

Связывать хочу их для того, чтобы находясь на странице поста и при смене языка попадал на нужный пост а не на 404 страницу, если вдруг слаг будет отличаться.
например

```
site.com/ru/post-1

site.com/en/my-post-1
```

В моем случае это один пост на разных языках, но слаг у них разный.

Comment: Что такое `слаг`? Недавно делал мультиязычный сайт, возможно вы там найдёте что-то полезное: http://dont-play-with-google.com/. Ссылки на исходники - в подвале.

Comment: slug уникальный адрес сущности

Comment: "как их адекватно связать, чтобы в будущем проблем со скоростью при выборке не было" - а какие критические проблемы со скоростью должны возникнуть если делать согласно предложенной на вашем скриншоте схеме?

Comment: не знаю, потому и спрашиваю )